# No response from Docker service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I tried following the tutorial here
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/.

First issue I ran into was when I called `docker swarm init`. It also asked for docker `swarm init --advertise-addr` with one of two possible IPv6 IPs.

I tried initializing the swarm on both and then starting the service. The service starts succesfully, but I can't get any response when accessing `Localhost:4000`. It just loads forever.

I have tried rebuilding the image, creating the swarm on both IPs, checking the logs (there was nothing there), but I kind of run out of ideas. If it helps, the computer has dual operating system, might affect the networking in ways I an unable to figure out.

How can I receive a response on my request?

Comment: I would recommend you use https://labs.play-with-docker.com/ to test swarm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was facing was a connection between google chrome and docker swarm, documented better here
https://forums.docker.com/t/google-chrome-and-localhost-in-swarm-mode/32229/9.

There is no apparent solution